# Как заставить работать Virtual Box на ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

При попытке создания виртуальной машины virtual box на ubuntu 15.04 вываливаются сразу две ошибки, одна говорит что не установлен vboxdrv
но он установлен да и если запустить повтороно все равно ту же самую ошибку будет выдавать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сам результат запуска '/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'
ошибок не выдает, логи

sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                                                                                                                 [ OK ] 
 * Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules                                                                                                                                                    [ OK ] 
 * Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS                                                                                                                                        [ OK ] 
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules

**UPD 14:05:**

---

```
root@symantec-N55SL: virtualbox

WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-lowlatency.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
VirtualBox: Error -610 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime!
VirtualBox: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so",) failed: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls-deb0.so.28: symbol asn1_delete_structure2, version LIBTASN1_0_3 not defined in file libtasn1.so.6 with link time reference

VirtualBox: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.

root@symantec-N55SL:/usr/lib/vmware/modules# sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Уже установлена самая новая версия virtualbox-dkms.
virtualbox-dkms установлен вручную.
Следующие пакеты устанавливались автоматическиsymantec и больше не требуются:
  gcc-4.9-base:i386 gir1.2-gtk-vnc-2.0 gir1.2-libvirt-glib-1.0 gir1.2-spice-client-glib-2.0 gir1.2-spice-client-gtk-3.0 gnome-icon-theme libcaca0:i386 libcurl3:i386 libgtk-vnc-2.0-0 libgvnc-1.0-0
  libidn11:i386 libpython2.7:i386 libpython2.7-minimal:i386 libpython2.7-stdlib:i386 libreadline6:i386 librtmp1:i386 libsdl1.2debian:i386 libspice-client-glib-2.0-8 libspice-client-gtk-3.0-4
  libusbredirhost1 libvirt-glib-1.0-0 libxmu6:i386 python-ipaddr python-libxml2 python-pycurl python-urlgrabber spice-client-glib-usb-acl-helper virt-viewer virtinst
Для их удаления используйте «apt-get autoremove».
обновлено 0, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 6 пакетов не обновлено.
не установлено до конца или удалено 3 пакетов.
После данной операции, объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 0 B.
Хотите продолжить? [Д/н] y
Настраивается пакет virtualbox (4.3.26-dfsg-2ubuntu2) …
insserv: script virtualbox: service vboxdrv already provided!
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета virtualbox (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет virtualbox-qt:
 virtualbox-qt зависит от virtualbox (= 4.3.26-dfsg-2ubuntu2), однако:
  Пакет virtualbox пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета virtualbox-qt (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет virtualbox-dkms:
 virtualbox-dkms зависит от virtualbox (>= 4.3.26-dfsg-2ubuntu2), однако:
  Пакет virtualbox пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
Отчёты apport не записаны, так как сообщение об ошибке указывает на повторную ошибку от предыдущего отказа.
Отчёты apport не записаны, так как сообщение об ошибке указывает на повторную ошибку от предыдущего отказа.
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 virtualbox
 virtualbox-qt
 virtualbox-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: virtualbox установлен из репозитория дистрибутива?

Comment: попробуйте установить VB из Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: устанавливал как из репо так и скачивал с сайта (последние две версии проверял) - результат на скрине. забыл написать - os ubuntu 15.04

Comment: ключевая проблема здесь та же самая, что и в [другом вашем вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428462/178576): отсутствующий символ asn1_delete_structure2. там вы написали, что проблема с отсутствующим символом решена. вероятно, и с dkms-ом теперь проблема решилась?

Answer (score 2):

во-первых, естественно, устанавливать пакеты лучше из репозитория дистрибутива, а не «со стороны» (в том числе и с сайта разработчиков программы).

во-вторых, попробуйте «насильственно» удалить пакеты:

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge --force-all virtualbox virtualbox-qt virtualbox-dkms
```

если команда завершится ошибкой в каких-нибудь `pre-remove` или `post-remove` скриптах от какого-нибудь из пакетов, то подредактируйте (или, в конце концов, удалите) соответствующий(-ие) файл(-ы):

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/пакет.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/пакет.prerm
```

удалив там строки вида `set -e` (обычно в самом начале файла), и заменив коды возврата в всех командах вида `exit число` на ноль, т.е., чтобы команды выглядели как `exit 0`.

после редактирования повторите приведенную команду.

а дальше удалите зависимости этих пакетов, и поставтьте их заново:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox virtualbox-dkms
```

Answer (score 0):

установите пакет dkms, это модуль ядра потом выполните команду которая указана вам. и ребут на всякий пожарный.
Я как раз сейчас на suse 13.1 обновил дистрибутив, помогло, если установка dkms с пересборкой модуля ядра не поможет обновите дистрибутив. или пересоберите ядро на более свежую версию.
3.11.10-29-desktop вот моя версия ядра после обновления

Comment: проверил, выдает ошибки при установке dkms обновил сообщение в топике

Comment: apt-get upgrade самый легкий случай, либо пересборка модуля ядра с последующим подключением, выполните uname -a и скиньте результат сюда

Comment: @Symantec выполните uname -a и скиньте результат, думаю в 15.04 свежее ядро

Comment: "uname -a" - Linux symantec-N55SL 3.19.0-18-lowlatency #18-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Tue May 19 19:02:50 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: apt-get upgrade пробовал, не помогает

Comment: @Symantec да и не должен был помочь, у вас ядро свежее чем мое. попробейте снести virtualbox подчистую и скомпилить с исходников включая модуль ядра.